# How to use default and custom validators together? How to define their order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my model class:

```
class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :beginning_date, :end_date
  validates :beginning_date, :end_date :presence => true

  # custom validators
  validate :dates_cant_be_in_the_past

  def dates_cant_be_in_the_past
    if Date.parse(beginning_date) < Date.today
      errors.add(:beginning_date, "cant be in the past")
    end

    if Date.parse(end_date) < Date.today
      errors.add(:end_date, "cant be in the past")
    end
  end
end
```

Now two things should happen: At first validate the presence of the `beginning_date` and `end_date` attributes and than run my `dates_cant_be_in_the_past`validator.
Sadly this approach doesn't work. If I leave a field empty the `Date.parse`method throws an exception, because the argument is obviously empty.

Is it possible to define the order of default and custom validations? Or do I have to implement the presence validator myself, so I would do something like:

```
validate :dates_cant_be_blank, :dates_cant_be_in_the_past
```

The [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods) at least says:

> You can pass more than one symbol for each class method and the respective validations will be run in the same order as they were registered.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler if you create a validator for that:

```
class DateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if Date.parse(value) < Date.today
      record.errors.add(attribute, "cant be in the past")
    end
  end
end
```

And at your model you would use it like this:

```
class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :beginning_date, :end_date
  validates :beginning_date, :end_date :presence => true
  validates :beginning_date, :end_date, :date => true, :allow_blank => true
end
```

The `:allow_blank` piece if the one prevents the validation from running if the value is empty. Using a real validator object also removes the code form your model making it much simpler and removing the duplication you currently have.

Comment: Your solution works very well. Thank you. Another question: is it possible to compare my beginning and end date with your approach? I want to make sure that the beginning date occurs before the end date.

Comment: You can use the same validator and add the code in there or create a new one that would do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :beginning_date, :end_date
  validates :beginning_date, :end_date : presence => true

  # custom validators
  validate :valid_dates


  def valid_dates
    if valid_string(beginning_date)
      errors.add(:beginning_date, "Can't be in the past") unless Date.parse(beginning_date) > Date.today
    end

    if valid_string(end_date)
      errors.add(:end_date, "Can't be in the past") unless Date.parse(end_date) > Date.today
    end

  end

  def valid_string(test_value)
    test.value.is_a? String
  end

end
```